# dataframe filtering with checking the conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id      action          date          value

A       enter          20/12/2021       0
A       enter          20/12/2021      150
A       L-1            20/12/2021      520
A       L-2            20/12/2021      50
A       L-2            20/12/2021      550
A       L-3            20/12/2021      20
A       L-4            20/12/2021      5
A       L-5            20/12/2021      1
B       enter          25/12/2021      2
B       L-1            25/12/2021      510
B       L-2            25/12/2021      6
B       L-3            25/12/2021      3
C       enter          26/12/2021      4
C       L-1            26/12/2021      10
C       L-2            26/12/2021      20
```

Expected Data frame :

```
Id      action          date          value

A       L-3            20/12/2021      20
A       L-4            20/12/2021      5
A       L-5            20/12/2021      1
B       L-2            25/12/2021      6
B       L-3            25/12/2021      3
C       enter          26/12/2021      4
C       L-1            26/12/2021      10
C       L-2            26/12/2021      20
```

I am looking to filter out the rows before the last appearance of value > 500.
i.e. if the value is greater than 500 and no other value after that is greater than 500 then only those rows need to kept that appears after the last value > 500

tried `grouping Id` but stuck with applying the conditions.

Comment: is there always a value > 500? If not, do you want to keep or drop?

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a value >500 in each group, you can use a reverse [`groupby.cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.loc[df.loc[::-1, 'value'].le(500).groupby(df['Id']).cummin()]
```

output:

```
   Id action        date  value
5   A    L-3  20/12/2021     20
6   A    L-4  20/12/2021      5
7   A    L-5  20/12/2021      1
10  B    L-2  25/12/2021      6
11  B    L-3  25/12/2021      3
```

intermediates:

```
   Id action        date  value  le(500)  reverse cummin
0   A  enter  20/12/2021      0     True           False
1   A  enter  20/12/2021    150     True           False
2   A    L-1  20/12/2021    520    False           False
3   A    L-2  20/12/2021     50     True           False
4   A    L-2  20/12/2021    550    False           False
5   A    L-3  20/12/2021     20     True            True
6   A    L-4  20/12/2021      5     True            True
7   A    L-5  20/12/2021      1     True            True
8   B  enter  25/12/2021      2     True           False
9   B    L-1  25/12/2021    510    False           False
10  B    L-2  25/12/2021      6     True            True
11  B    L-3  25/12/2021      3     True            True
```

If there isn't always a value >500, you need a second mask:

```
g = df.loc[::-1, 'value'].le(500).groupby(df['Id'])

m1 = g.cummin()           # drop rows with >500 and before
m2 = ~g.transform('all')  # drop groups without value >500

out = df.loc[m1&m2]
```

##### with previous value:

```
g = df.loc[::-1, 'value'].le(500).groupby(df['Id'])
m1 = g.transform(lambda s: s.cummin().shift().bfill())
m2 = ~g.transform('all')

out = df.loc[m1&m2]
```

output:

```
   Id action        date  value
4   A    L-2  20/12/2021    550
5   A    L-3  20/12/2021     20
6   A    L-4  20/12/2021      5
7   A    L-5  20/12/2021      1
9   B    L-1  25/12/2021    510
10  B    L-2  25/12/2021      6
11  B    L-3  25/12/2021      3
```

Comment: thanks.!! if the Id does not have any value greater than 500 , does this code work..?

Comment: @Roshankumar that was the point of my question, you said there is always a value. Please update your example with a group without value >500 and the matching expected output.

Comment: kudos..!! what if that value need to kept and not dropped..? plz guide

Comment: Then the first approach keep the value or you mean the value above threshold? Then replace `.cummin()` with `.apply(lambda s: s.cummin().shift(-1).ffill())`

Comment: Should be `shift()` and  `bfill` sorry (`s.cummin().shift().bfill()`), I forgot the series was reversed ;)

Comment: no worries..!! its sorted. thanks for help rockstar

Comment: (s.cummin().shift().bfill()) doesn,t give boolean series.. any suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, it worked fine for me

Comment: m1 = g.apply(lambda s: s.cummin().shift().bfill())

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'

Comment: I can't check now, but what about: `m1 = g.apply(lambda s: s.cummin().shift().bfill()).fillna(False)`?

Comment: still the same error. all i need is that the row where the condition is meet has to be included. shift will include it but it excludes the last row as well which is not required

Comment: @Roshankumar see the update, this works as I said… not sure what you did